# huawei dongle E8231 support ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers

I bought a Huawei wi-fi dongle but I can't connect it. Please help me install this Huawei dongle in Ubuntu 14.04. Is a driver needed for it?

It is a Huawei Power-Fi E8231: 
http://www.huaweidevice.co.in/?q=huawei-power-fi-e8231

Comment: Hi, Did you get any success?